# PHP exec or shell_exec only executes commands but not files on Win10 + Wampserver

Tags: php, windows, wamp, wampserver

I am losing my mind about an issue with php exec() or shell_exec() functions not being able to run any file on windows 10 .

I have been researching this for several hours now and tried everything I could come up with so far, but any exec command called through php only works for commands but not for running scripts or files .

So for the purpose of debugging, I made the following php script to return values of 0 and 1 according to the command being executed successfully or not :

```
<?php

$return = -1;
exec('C:\\wamp64\\www\\macro\\run.bat',$out,$return);
echo "Return value: $return\n";
var_dump($out);
    
?>
```

I get the following output from the script :

```
Return value: 0
C:\wamp64\www\macro\run.php:9:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'C:\wamp64\www\macro>start "" "C:\wamp64\www\macro\run.lnk"' (length=58)
```

This indicates my script was ran correctly and in fact the string shows me the command inside the .bat file .

However, the file doesn't actually get executed , I tried multiple files such as notepad, etc and nothing works !

Here's what I have tried so far :

1. Making sure safe_mode wasn't enabled in php.ini and same for disable_functions (no issues here, as every exec command works as expected except for running files)
2. I tried as suggested in other topics to change my wampapache64 service Log On properties to both local administrator account with password and Local system account checking the "allow service to interact with desktop" option
3. I restarted wamp multiple times
4. I made sure Wamp was running as administrator
5. I tried using double slashes \ for the file path

Please notice it doesn't work for any file extension, be it a .exe or .bat

At this point I've given up trying to get it to work and can't really see what else could possibly be causing it .

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your interpretations here make no sense: "This indicates my script was ran correctly and in fact the string shows me the command inside the .bat file .

However, the file doesn't actually get executed" How about you tell us what you did, what you expected to happen and what you observed (*NOT* just your interpretation). Provide a [mcve] which doesn't involve guessing in any way.

Comment: How is that guessing ? You have a php script which outputs 0 when a file is ran correctly , it's not an interpretation in any sense ! 

The fact is that although the php script indicates a correct execution of the exec command the file doesn't actually run on windows . 

if it was executed successfully it should return 0. If the file was not found, it will return 1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is related to running a GUI service and allowing it to interact with desktop .

Even though I had previously tried running the service as Administrator user and also ticking the enable service to interact with desktop option in the Log on properties, for some reason I am unable to explain it didn't work as expected .

I found a hack in another thread which did it for me, I'm sure it can save some headaches for anyone coming across this issue :

```
<?php
function _exec($cmd)
{
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN _proc /TR "' . $cmd . '"" /SC DAILY /RU INTERACTIVE');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "_proc"');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "_proc" /F');
}
_exec("mspaint.exe");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A batch is not a valid binary executable. Just call it with the proper `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You can execute batch files through php . Either way, it doesn't work with exes too, that's why I created the batch in the first place .